# Flutter: A FocusNode was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter

I have a simple Flutter form inside a stateful widget with a bunch of text fields to capture credit card details. And when I show this form, tap the first field, type something in it, then tap the second field, the focus is not transferred to the second field, the cursor stays in the first one, even though both fields appear focused (border is visible on both) and when I type, it goes in the first field. The only way to type something into the second field is to long tap it as if I wanted to paste something in it. And in the console, I see this:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
Once you have called dispose() on a FocusNode, it can no longer be used.
#0      ChangeNotifier._debugAssertNotDisposed.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:117:9)
#1      ChangeNotifier._debugAssertNotDisposed (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:123:6)
#2      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:234:12)
#3      FocusNode._notify (package:flutter/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart:1052:5)
#4      FocusManager._applyFocusChange (package:flutter/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart:1800:12)
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)
#6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
#7      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
```

The thing is that none of the fields have a focus node-set, so it seems something wrong is happening inside the Flutter form state. Has anybody seen this?

Note that for me, it occurs on the web and mobile alike, but not consistently.

Here is the code of the [problematic form](https://github.com/ezet/stripe-sdk/blob/b4e027a18e177653f9d0ad3931f71c9e26711901/lib/src/ui/widgets/card_form.dart).

And here is a screenshot illustrating 2 fields having focus at the same time, and the cursor is stuck in the first one. And when I type something on the keyboard, it's directed at the first field. This is running on a physical iPhone device.

[image]

And here is the function that is called as the `onPressed` of an `ElevatedButton` to show this form:

```
Future<void> _addPaymentMethod(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          body: CardForm(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you share some code, so that we can learn from that .

Comment: Would you share a code related to FocusNode's dispose place?

Comment: Sure, I will add a link to the form in the message, but here it is: https://github.com/ezet/stripe-sdk/blob/b4e027a18e177653f9d0ad3931f71c9e26711901/lib/src/ui/widgets/card_form.dart

Comment: @KuKu, as you can see in the code I just linked, there is no FocusNode dispose in the form.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have this error when I show a `showModalBottomSheet`

Comment: @Sebastien Do you use the flutter form builder package?

Comment: @AliHesari Not in this instance, as you can see in the code I linked, but I've had a similar issue with flutter_form_builder in the past, which leads me to think it might be something internal with focus traversal in Flutter forms in specific circumstances.

Comment: @Sebastien I found a link about this problem but it is for form builder. I tried it and it does not work for me. I thought maybe it be useful for you: https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/issues/313

Comment: If I understand that correctly, the error is with the SDK code and not with your app code ? @Sebastien

Comment: @SwaminathanV that's what I would like to confirm. Because if it's with the SDK, I don't see any mention of that exact bug in Flutter's Github issues so either I'm the first one to notice (unlikely) or I'm doing something I'm not supposed to do (way more likely)

Comment: Understood. Please add your code snippet on how you are calling/building card form in your app. It might be helpful to narrow down the issue. @Sebastien

Comment: @SwaminathanV I added the calling code to the question

Comment: Have you tried the example app provided along with the library. It is working as expected. May be you can try it in the different device or emulator. And let know if issue still persist. @Sebastien

Comment: Are you using the package `flutter_form_builder`? I saw a reported issue below: [Bug multiple textinput focused](https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/issues/683)

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is using Focus widget.

You should be using FocusNode and pass this FocusNode as one of the named arguments of TextField (your CardCvcFormField).

You can attach a listener to the FocusNode and get the focus visibility.

```
FocusNode _cvcFocusNode;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cvcFocusNode = FocusNode();
    _cvcFocusNode.addListener(_onCvcFormFieldFocusChanged);
}

void _onCvcFormFieldFocusChanged() {
   setState(() => cvcHasFocus = _cvcFocusNode?.hasFocus ?? false);
}

@override
void dispose() {
   _cvcFocusNode?.removeListener(_onCvcFormFieldFocusChanged);
   _cvcFocusNode?.dispose();
   _cvcFocusNode = null;
   super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I removed the Focus widget and replaced it with your technique, but I still have the issue on mobile web browsers. I tried forcing the canvaskit rendering engine, but to no avail, I still have this bug.

Answer (score 0):

once check the focusNode is used more than once anywhere. Or you have disposed the focus node twice in dispose() method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).